# Porque tengo este error Node y NPM

Tags: nodejs, npm, angular-cli

Necesito ayudan con esto alguien que me pueda ayudar gracias:
Tengo node -v 10 y npm -v 6

al intentar intalar angular-cli me genera este error en la consola estoy usando windows 10

> 17 error code E405 18 error 405 Method Not Allowed: angular-cli@latest
>   19 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Comment: Podrias intentar esto en consola                                                                    
$ npm remove -g angular-cli
$ npm cache clean
$ npm install -g angular-cli                                                                                     Y me avisas que paso

Comment: Si eso fue lo que hice, ya el problema esta resulto.. busque de manera global en el disco local c: este archivo `.npmrc` elimine todas los resultados con el mismo nombre, intente nuevamente con las instalaciones y me dio resultado exitoso.. en mi caso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La manera en la que resolví el inconveniente luego de una búsqueda extensa en la web, fue  buscando en el disco local c de manera global este archivo `.npmrc` procedí con eliminarlo y para finalizar  realice los siguientes paso:

> npm uninstall -g angular-cli
>
> npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
>
> npm cache clean -f
>
> npm install -g angular-cli
>
> npm install -g @angular/cli

Y me instalo todo de manera correcta